Prove that every 2x2 matrix over complex field is a product of at most 2 diagonalizable matrices.
I got this question in my Advanced Linear Algebra assignment. But couldn't figure out a way to solve this.
Also, what about this statement for any matrix over complex field Mn(C).

Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match many users' quality standards, so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. This will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

In the $2\times2$ case, any characteristc polynomial is either of the form $(x-\lambda_1)(x-\lambda_2)$ or $(x-\lambda)^2$. In the first case, a matrix with such a characteristic polynomial is already diagonalizable. In the second case, we can write our matrix $A$ as $$A = P \begin{bmatrix} \lambda & 1 \\ 0 & \lambda \end{bmatrix}P^{-1},$$ i.e., in its Jordan form. Thus, we need to verify the statement only for the Jordan block $\begin{bmatrix} \lambda & 1 \\ 0 & \lambda \end{bmatrix}$. We note that:
$$ \begin{bmatrix} \lambda & 1 \\ 0 & \lambda \end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & \lambda \end{bmatrix}\cdot\begin{bmatrix} \lambda & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix},$$
which is a product of two diagonalizable matrices.

This question doesn’t meet the standards for the site. Instead of answering it (which encourages low-quality questions), why not look for a good duplicate target, or help the user by posting comments suggesting improvements? Please also read the meta announcement regarding quality standards.

@AleK3 Thanks for answering the question. Really appreciate it. It was simple but I was thinking about it in more complicated ways than was necessary.
